# How to divide the region into smaller size regions using latitude, longitude and radius(distance), in Google place Search API in Java?

Tags: java, google-places-api, google-api-java-client, jsonresponse

I am using google radar place search API in Java. I am giving request using latitude,longitude and radius (distance) of particular region. I am getting about 200 responses (Maximum by this API). If I get 200 responses, I have to divide my request into smaller sizes using latitude and longitude, so that I can cover the full region of the circle to get details about all the places in that region. So, how to divide the Circular region using latitude, longitude and radius? So only, I can get each and every places in that region. Please, help me out.

Here is the code,

Method to invoke the API,
I gave my latitude, longitude, type= restaurant, radius = 20000 (to find out the restaurants in that region within 20 kms)

```
public void performGooglePlaceSearch(double lati,double lang,int rad,String type,String key)
{ 

  try{ 
            String placeSearchURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location="+lati+","+lang+"&radius="+rad+"&types="+type+"&key="+key;


            Client placeSearchClient = Client.create();
            WebResource placeSearchWebResource = placeSearchClient.resource(placeSearchURL);
            ClientResponse placeSearchClientResponse = placeSearchWebResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class); //Here I will receive the json response.

            String placeSearchOutput = placeSearchClientResponse.getEntity(String.class);


            System.out.println(placeSearchOutput);

            //To convert to Java object, I use this classes. Because, I need to convert from Json response to Java object.
            ObjectMapper placeSearchMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            // I created java classes in PlaceSearchResponse class for all the json responses I received, ie, latitude, longitude, id, place_id, 
            PlaceSearchResponse placeSearchResponse=placeSearchMapper.readValue(new URL(placeSearchURL), PlaceSearchResponse.class); 

            //Iterating all the Java objects ie, latitude, longitude, id, place_id
            Iterator iter=(Iterator) placeSearchResponse.getResults().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
                PlacesInfo placeDetails=(PlacesInfo) iter.next();
            }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

From this above code, after iterating, I get maximum of 200 responses. This API gives maximum of 200 results only, because, it is limited to 200. If I get 200 results, then there will more no of responses be available. I need to break this region into more small regions, so that I can get more no of restaurants available in this region.

Comment: I am giving input as Latitude, Longitude and Radius (Distance) to find out the restaurant in that region. I am getting around 200 responses (responses about 200 restaurants). If this API gives maximum of 200 responses means, then there is more places available in that region. So, that I want to break up this region into smaller regions to get the details of all places available there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minPriceLevel and maxPriceLevel` to split search into four results ie 0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4

```
String placeSearchURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location="+lati+","+lang+"&radius="+rad+"&types="+type+"&minprice="+min"+"&maxprice="+max"+ &key="+key;
```

Comment: I am asking about, if I get about 200 responses, then I need to break up the region into smaller sizes. So only, I can get more results from that area. Because, this API gives maximum of 200 responses only. So, how to break up that region?

Comment: You can't break up the region(circle) and use radar search. You can either reduce radius or limit the responses. The way I have suggested would be the simplest. `name` & `opennow` are others but I don't think they would be suitable especially  `opennow`   as there is no   `notopennow`

Comment: By reducing radius and changing various latitude/longitude, we can cover up the circle by small regions (circles). Fot that small circles we can invoke the API and get the more responses.

Comment: Yes you can but you will need many smaller circles and you may miss some of the places if you don't cover all the circle Or if you overlap the outside of the 200 radius you will get more places. It is up to you how you do it as it depends on your needs.